# I lost my data when i scroll horizontal and vertical on view in Android

Tags: android

Em...the title is not clearly, here is my question: i custom a view to display calendar, my logic is when user swipe horizontal it can switch month of current year, when user swipe vertical it can switch year of current month, like image below:

[image]

Here is my all code below and i delete some useless code:

```
public class MonthView extends View {
private static final Region[][] MONTH_REGIONS = new Region[6][7]; 

private DPCManager mCManager = DPCManager.getInstance(); 
private DPTManager mTManager = DPTManager.getInstance(); 

private TextPaint mTextPaint;
private Paint mPaint;
private Scroller mScroller; 
private DecelerateInterpolator decelerateInterpolator = new DecelerateInterpolator(); 
private AccelerateInterpolator accelerateInterpolator = new AccelerateInterpolator(); 

private OnDateChangeListener onDateChangeListener;
private ScaleAnimationListener scaleAnimationListener = new ScaleAnimationListener();

private DPMode mode;

private int indexYear, indexMonth; 
private int centerYear, centerMonth; 
private int leftYear, leftMonth; 
private int rightYear, rightMonth; 
private int topYear, topMonth;
private int bottomYear, bottomMonth;
private int width, height; 
private int lastHeight, nextHeight; 
private int baseSize; 
private int sizeDecor, sizeDecor2x, sizeDecor3x; 
private int lastPointX, lastPointY; 
private int lastMoveX, lastMoveY; 
private int criticalWidth, criticalHeight; 

private float sizeTextGregorian, sizeTextFestival; 
private float offsetYFestival1, offsetYFestival2; 

private boolean isSlideV; 

private Map<String, BGCircle> circlesAppear = new HashMap<>(); 
private Map<String, BGCircle> circlesDisappear = new HashMap<>(); 

private List<String> dateSelected = new ArrayList<>(); 

public interface OnDateChangeListener {
    void onMonthChange(int month);

    void onYearChange(int year);
}

public MonthView(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public MonthView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    mScroller = new Scroller(context);
    mTextPaint = new TextPaint();
    mTextPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
    mPaint = new Paint();
}

void setOnDateChangeListener(OnDateChangeListener onDateChangeListener) {
    this.onDateChangeListener = onDateChangeListener;
}

void setMode(DPMode mode) {
    this.mode = mode;
}

void setDate(int year, int month) {
    centerYear = year;
    centerMonth = month;
    indexYear = 0;
    indexMonth = 0;
    computeDate();
    requestLayout();
    invalidate();
}

private void computeDate() {
    rightYear = leftYear = centerYear;

    topYear = centerYear - 1;
    bottomYear = centerYear + 1;

    topMonth = centerMonth;
    bottomMonth = centerMonth;

    rightMonth = centerMonth + 1;
    leftMonth = centerMonth - 1;

    if (centerMonth == 12) {
        rightYear++;
        rightMonth = 1;
    }

    if (centerMonth == 1) {
        leftYear--;
        leftMonth = 12;
    }

    if (null != onDateChangeListener) {
        onDateChangeListener.onYearChange(centerYear);
        onDateChangeListener.onMonthChange(centerMonth);
    }
}

@Override
public void computeScroll() {
    if (mScroller.computeScrollOffset()) {
        scrollTo(mScroller.getCurrX(), mScroller.getCurrY());
    } else {
    }
}
boolean isNewEvent = false;

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            isNewEvent = true;
            lastPointX = (int) event.getX();
            lastPointY = (int) event.getY();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (isNewEvent) {
                if (Math.abs(lastPointX - event.getX()) > 100) {
                    isSlideV = false;
                    isNewEvent = false;
                } else if (Math.abs(lastPointY - event.getY()) > 50) {
                    isSlideV = true;
                    isNewEvent = false;
                }
            }
            if (isSlideV) {
                int totalMoveY = (int) (lastPointY - event.getY()) + lastMoveY;
                smoothScrollTo(0, totalMoveY);
            } else {
                int totalMoveX = (int) (lastPointX - event.getX()) + lastMoveX;
                smoothScrollTo(totalMoveX, 0);
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            if (isSlideV) {
                if (Math.abs(lastPointY - event.getY()) > 25) {
                    if (lastPointY < event.getY()) { 
                        if (Math.abs(lastPointY - event.getY()) >= criticalHeight) { 
                            indexYear--;
                            centerYear = centerYear - 1;
                            computeDate();
                        }
                        smoothScrollTo(0, height * indexYear);
                        lastMoveY = height * indexYear;
                    } else if (lastPointY > event.getY()) { 
                        if (Math.abs(lastPointY - event.getY()) >= criticalHeight) { 
                            indexYear++;
                            centerYear = centerYear + 1;
                            computeDate();
                        }
                        smoothScrollTo(0, height * indexYear);
                        lastMoveY = height * indexYear;
                    }
                } else {
                }
            } else {
                if (Math.abs(lastPointX - event.getX()) > 25) {
                    if (lastPointX > event.getX()) { 
                        if (Math.abs(lastPointX - event.getX()) >= criticalWidth) { 
                            indexMonth++;
                            centerMonth = (centerMonth + 1) % 13;
                            if (centerMonth == 0) {
                                centerMonth = 1;
                                centerYear++;
                            }
                            computeDate();
                        }
                        smoothScrollTo(width * indexMonth, 0);
                        lastMoveX = width * indexMonth;
                    } else if (lastPointX < event.getX()) { 
                        if (Math.abs(lastPointX - event.getX()) >= criticalWidth) { 
                            indexMonth--;
                            centerMonth = (centerMonth - 1) % 12;
                            if (centerMonth == 0) {
                                centerMonth = 12;
                                centerYear--;
                            }
                            computeDate();
                        }
                        smoothScrollTo(width * indexMonth, 0);

                        lastMoveX = width * indexMonth;
                    }
                } else {
                }
            }
            break;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {       
    int measureWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(measureWidth, measureWidth * 6 / 7F);
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldW, int oldH) {
    width = w;
    height = h;

    criticalWidth = (int) (1F / 5F * width);
    criticalHeight = (int) (1F / 5F * height);

    baseSize = w;

    int sizeCell = (int) (baseSize / 7F);

    sizeDecor = (int) (sizeCell / 3F);
    sizeDecor2x = sizeDecor * 2;
    sizeDecor3x = sizeDecor * 3;

    sizeTextGregorian = baseSize / 20F;
    mTextPaint.setTextSize(sizeTextGregorian);

    float heightGregorian = mTextPaint.getFontMetrics().bottom - mTextPaint.getFontMetrics().top;

    sizeTextFestival = baseSize / 40F;
    mTextPaint.setTextSize(sizeTextFestival);

    float heightFestival = mTextPaint.getFontMetrics().bottom - mTextPaint.getFontMetrics().top;

    offsetYFestival1 = (((Math.abs(mTextPaint.ascent() + mTextPaint.descent())) / 2F) +
            heightFestival / 2F + heightGregorian / 2F) / 2F;
    offsetYFestival2 = offsetYFestival1 * 2F;

    for (int i = 0; i < MONTH_REGIONS.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < MONTH_REGIONS[i].length; j++) {
            Region region = new Region();
            region.set((j * sizeCell), (i * sizeCell), sizeCell + (j * sizeCell),
                    sizeCell + (i * sizeCell));
            MONTH_REGIONS[i][j] = region;
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawColor(Color.LTGRAY);

    draw(canvas, width * (indexMonth - 1), height * indexYear, leftYear, leftMonth);
    draw(canvas, width * indexMonth, height * indexYear, centerYear, centerMonth);
    draw(canvas, width * (indexMonth + 1), height * indexYear, rightYear, rightMonth);

    draw(canvas, width * indexMonth, height * (indexYear - 1), topYear, topMonth);

    draw(canvas, width * indexMonth, height * (indexYear + 1), bottomYear, bottomMonth);
}


private void draw(Canvas canvas, int x, int y, int year, int month) {
    canvas.save();
    canvas.translate(x, y);

    DPInfo[][] info = mCManager.obtainDPInfo(year, month);
    for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < info[i].length; j++) {
            draw(canvas, MONTH_REGIONS[i][j].getBounds(), info[i][j]);
        }
    }
    canvas.restore();
}

private void draw(Canvas canvas, Rect rect, DPInfo info) {
    drawGregorian(canvas, rect, info.strG, info.isWeekend);
}

private void drawGregorian(Canvas canvas, Rect rect, String str, boolean isWeekend) {
    mTextPaint.setTextSize(sizeTextGregorian);
    if (isWeekend) {
        mTextPaint.setColor(mTManager.colorWeekend());
    } else {
        mTextPaint.setColor(mTManager.colorG());
    }
    canvas.drawText(str, rect.centerX(), rect.centerY(), mTextPaint);
}

private void smoothScrollTo(int fx, int fy) {
    int dx = fx - mScroller.getFinalX();
    int dy = fy - mScroller.getFinalY();
    smoothScrollBy(dx, dy);
}

private void smoothScrollBy(int dx, int dy) {
    mScroller.startScroll(mScroller.getFinalX(), mScroller.getFinalY(), dx, dy, 500);
    invalidate();
}
```

}

If i swipe vertical to switch year, for example 2015/7-->2016/7-->2017/7, it's run correctly, but now if i swipe horizontal to switch month, for example 2017/7-->2017/6, everything will not display:

[image]

That's mean only horizontal and vertical on current month can touch and display correctly, for example the default display month is 2015/7, when i swipe to 2016/7 or 2017/7, i can't get the correct display when i swipe to 2017/6 or 2017/8, only swipe back to 2015/7 to swipe correctly can get the correct display of 2015/6 and 2015/8.

This problem troubled me many days, the coordinates and data of months all correct, i don't know why it happen, hope and thanks for your answer.